# After Oracle 11gR2 restore & recover database, "ghost" NOLOGGING corrupt blocks

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, corruption

I recently restored (from full, level 0 cold backup) an `ARCHIVELOG` database & recovered it to a point in time about 24 hours after backup. I ran `RMAN validate` and numerous blocks turned up in `V$DATABASE_BLOCK_CORRUPTION` with corruption of `NOLOGGING`.  This was anticipated as database has frequent `NOLOGGING` load operations.  The game-plan was to map `V$DATABASE_BLOCK_CORRUPTION` blocks to segments (table partitions), truncate partition, and replay the loads of those data sets from source files.

In most cases, this worked perfectly; most entries in `V$DATABASE_BLOCK_CORRUPTION` mapped directly to `NOLOGGING` table partitions which would've been loaded via `INSERT /*+APPEND*/` after the cold backup.

Only wrench: `V$DATABASE_BLOCK_CORRUPTION` shows about 100 blocks with `NOLOGGING` corruption that do not match any entries in `DBA_EXTENTS` (they are, presumably, unused blocks).

1) Any idea what caused these blocks to become corrupt?
2) As they do not map to any extents in use, can I safely ignore them?
3) The OCD question: if these blocks aren't problematic, is there a way to clear them from `V$DATABASE_BLOCK_CORRUPTION`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Presumably there was data in them at one point, which has since been deleted.
2. If the corrupted blocks are in free space, there is no need to take any action. Oracle will reformat the block when it attempts to use the space. So you can ignore the alerts.
3. If you want to clear the corrupt blocks to prevent more alerts, create a nologging table in the relevant tablespace. Insert a lot of rows until the corrupt blocks disappear, then drop the table.

Comment: That was my take as well, glad to see a matching opinion.  The ghost blocks seem "widely sprinkled" across several large datafiles, so I imagine I'd wind up running quite a mass of I/O to fill them all.  Definitely doesn't seem worth the effort.

Comment: Yeah if it's a production environment the cure may be worse than the disease. If you have access to Oracle support, check out Doc ID 336133.1 which has a lot more info and useful measures.